Are normal theories categorical in uncountable cardinalities?
I am interested in the theorem by Baldwin and Lachlan that uncountably categorical theories are either $\omega$-categorical or have exactly $\aleph_0$ countable models. I am trying to avoid going with the original proof from their paper On strongly minimal sets.
In Fundamentals of Stability theory, Baldwin points to a proof provided by Pillay in the paper Countable models of stable theories. Pillay uses the notion of normal theories and proves that such theories have the property above.
Here are the relevant definitions from Pillay's paper.

Definition: (i) The $L$-formula $\alpha(\overline{x}, \overline{y})$ is $T$-normal (or just normal) if for any
$\overline{a}, \overline{b}$ in a model $M$ of $T$ the definable
subsets $\alpha(\overline{x}, \overline{a})$ and $\alpha(\overline{x},
> \overline{b})$ are either disjoint or
equal.
(ii) $T$ is normal if every $L$-formula is equivalent modulo $T$ to a
Boolean combination of normal formulae (i.e. formulae that are normal
no matter how we separate the variables).

My question is, where could I find out what the relation between normal theories and $\aleph_1$-categoricity is? Does one imply the other? In particular is every $\aleph_1$-categorical theory normal? That seems to be a natural consequence of these theorems. If there is a specific result, what methods does it use? I am not very well acquainted with stability theory so I wonder if establishing a connection between these notions might be possible with simpler methods.

Please define "normal theory". This is not a standard term.

It would also be helpful to know your background and why you want to avoid the standard proof of Baldwin-Lachlan. At this point, there are several very readable expositions of the proof, e.g. in thr textbooks by Marker, Hodges, and (my favorite) Tent-Ziegler.

In the abstract of the paper it says "the property of normality is stronger than stability but incomparable to superstability."

Normal theory is a theory where every L-formula is normal. A formula is normal if for any $\bar{a}$, $\bar{b}$ in a model $\mathcal{M}$ of T the definable subsets $\alpha(\bar{x}, \bar{a})$ and $\alpha(\bar{x}, \bar{b})$ are either disjoint or equal. These definitions are given in the paper by Pillay I referenced.

I refer to the other proof by Baldwin and Lachlan that determines the number of countable models of uncountably categorical theories. Not the standard where categoricity is tied to $\omega$-stability and lack of Vaughtian pairs

I am a bachelor student and got interested in the proof. It is mentioned in Marker but no proof is provided and the only instance of it that I am able to understand seemingly without very deep knowledge of stability theory is this paper by Pillay.

Unless the theorem You Alex are referring to is the theorem 6.3.7 from Tent and Ziegler that seems to have the same character as the statement I had in mind. I was not aware of it being presented in TZ.

Welcome to Math Stackexchange! I took the liberty of editing your question, adding links to the papers and copying in the definitions from Pillay's paper. One of the rules of this site is that quesitons should be as self-contained as possible: the reader shouldn't have to track down a paper to understand what you're asking. Note that the definition of "normal theory" in your comment above is incorrect: we do not require that every $L$-formula is normal, just that every formula is equivalent to a Boolean combination of normal formulas.

Yes, the theorem you want is a direct consequence of Theorem 6.3.7 in Tent and Ziegler. Sorry, I forgot that Marker and Hodges only state the theorem but don't provide proofs.

There is no implication in either direction between normality and $\aleph_1$-categoricity.

The theory of an equivalence relation with two classes, both of which are infinite, is normal but not $\aleph_1$-categorical.
The theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ is $\aleph_1$-categorical but not normal.


Note that Pillay does not prove that a normal theory has either $1$ or $\aleph_0$ countable models. He proves that a normal theory has either $1$ or $\geq\aleph_0$ countable models, which still leaves open the possibility that the theory could have uncountably many countable models. In fact, there are normal theories in a countable language with $2^{\aleph_0}$-many countable models. Any non-superstable normal theory will do, such as the theory of infinitely many cross-cutting equivalence relations.
A theory $T$ is called an Ehrenfeucht theory if the number of countable models of $T$ is finite but greater than $1$. So Pillay's Theorem 13 can be rephrased as saying that no normal theory is Ehrenfeucht.
Pillay also proves in Theorem 9 that no superstable theory is Ehrenfeucht (this fact was previously proved by Lascar and Shelah, by different means). Every $\aleph_1$-categorical is theory $\omega$-stable, hence superstable, so Theorem 9 is more closely related to the Baldwin-Lachlan theorem than Theorem 13 is. But again, the Baldwin-Lachlan theorem gives a much stronger result in the uncountably categorical case, since it also rules out the case of uncountably many countable models.
